# CORS ORIGIN ISSUE NestJs

Tags: angular, nestjs

I matched this erorr: [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/courses from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:9000 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/erro...

Is there someone has a solution?

I've tried to add in app.module.ts (NestJS App) app.enableCors(); but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a proxy to your angular project. The Angular documentation describes this pretty well.

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Your URL which is called must look like this:

http://localhost:4200/api/courses

A sample proxy config for this would be this:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:9000/api",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

This can be read like this: Whenever there is a call to /api take the whole path until the end of /api, and change it to http://localhost:9000/api but leave the rest of the url the same.

So the proxy will redirect http://localhost:4200/api/courses to http://localhost:9000/api/courses

Comment: Indeed in Angular project, package.json I have: "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config ./proxy.json",

Comment: @Vinni I added more explanation and an example. Hope that helps